# Airflow - sql_alchemy_conn (Azure SQL Database)

Tags: azure-sql-database, airflow

I'm going to configure Airflow within Azure and we have a SQL Database available in the cloud, can I configure it within the airflow? Or does it need to be postgres?

If possible, could you put an example of his using the sql_alchemy_conn variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a document [Setting up Airflow on Azure & connecting to MS SQL Server](https://medium.com/analytics-and-data/setting-up-airflow-on-azure-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-8c06784a7e2b) may could help you.

Summary:

**MSSQL:**

Azure offers scalable managed SQL Server instances, which proves to be a good choice for a data repository. The base image of airflow from puckels’ however doesn’t interact with this database. In this specific case we are not looking at setting up a database to host airflow metadata (although possible), but rather as a target destination from some of the dags.

In order to take advantage of a connection to MsSQL, the MsSQL driver needs to be installed. The documentation on how to setup this driver for Linux is provided on Microsoft’s [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Since the latest puckel/docker-airflow image is based on “python:3.6-slim”, itself based on debian 9 “stretch”, we can add these dependencies to the image, by following the Debian 9 documentation on Microsoft’s website:

```
RUN apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc unixodbc-dev gnupg2 apt-transport-https curl -y \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools -y
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Once this is done a few packages will need to be installed through pip:

```
RUN  pip install 'apache-airflow[mssql]' \
                 'pyodbc' \
                 'pymssql'
```

The airflow[mssql] package adds the operator and hooks to interact with MsSQL while pyodbc and pymsqsl, provides a database interface to MsSQL. After having installed the driver and the python packages, we can now connect to the specified MsSQL server, using a SQL Alchemy connection string in the following format:

```
connectionString = \
"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

Hope this helps.